# Return a unique channel in clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

**Goal:** Construct a ClojureScript function that takes a string `s` and returns the unique channel with the name `(str s "-chan")` (if the channel doesn't exist, then create it). Here is my attempt:

```
(defn string-channel 
  [s]
  (let [chan-name (symbol (str s "-chan"))]
    (defonce chan-name (chan))
    chan-name))
```

This yields an error. How do I accomplish this goal? Note that since I'm in ClojureScript, I am unable to use the `eval` construct if the solution involves a macro.

Comment: Why not just put them in a map from string to channel?

Comment: you mentioned an error, could you perhaps include it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather propose to keep these channels in an atom (since defining vars dynamically seems really needless here). In addition, keeping channels in one place seems to me more manageable.

```
(def channels (atom {}))

(defn string-channel [s]
  (when-not (@channels s)
    (swap! channels assoc s (chan)))
  (@channels s))
```

Comment: This is the best solution. In addition to manageability, storing the channels in a map (via an atom) **gives you programmatic access to channel names in the form of map keywords**. That is, you cannot `(def (fn-returning-symbol) (chan))`, but you can `(assoc {} (fn-returning-keyword) (chan))`. This turned out to be a huge weakness for my solution below (not within the context of my question above, but within the context of the actual problem I was trying to solve when not abstracted into a more easily digested SE question).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the right approach was to use a `defmacro`:

```
(defmacro string-channel 
  [s]
   `(do
    (defonce ~(symbol (str s "-chan")) (chan))
   ~(symbol (str s "-chan"))))
```

Comment: See intern: http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/intern

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [memoize](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/memoize) if the intent is to ensure a unique channel for each label *s*:

```
(def unique-channel (memoize (fn [s] (chan))))
```